# How to list greencard status on a resume?

Tags: resume, united-states, hiring, visa

I am applying for a job in a US company. I have a green card and already live in town.

The company I am applying to has difficulty finding talent in the USA, so they often hire people from overseas on H1-B visas. Almost all of the recent new hires come from abroad. So, I am concerned if I apply, having a foreign name and nationality, they will assume that I am also not local and in need of an H1-B visa. I think this the green card status put me at an advantage, as the company will not need to go through the complicated process of applying for a H1-B visa, dealing with someone who is not adjusted to the culture, etc.

What is a professional way to list my visa status on my resume, such it is clear to HR that they will not need to apply for an H1-B? I am assuming that some of the HR staff may not understand visas.

Comment: When I was looking for jobs or applying for college I put "British Citizen,  US Permanent Resident" on my resume or CV. HR people will typically understand the concept of a permanent resident

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When looking for work in the US from abroad, how can I make it clear that I'll be in the country for interviews?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/81658/when-looking-for-work-in-the-us-from-abroad-how-can-i-make-it-clear-that-ill-b)

Comment: @ChristopherEstep I disagree with the duplicate Close vote. In the linked question, the OP is not a green card holder. While in this question, the OP is a green card holder.

Comment: I would leave the Visa/Green Card status off the table until you are in salary negotiation faze. Honestly, I don't give a hoot about that part when I'm looking to hire. I have a person on my staff who doesn't have his green card, it was up to HR to figure out that side. And having a name that could be foreign doesn't mean anything either. Unless the company specifically notes this on their job description or you are asked in the first round interview, leave it off.

Answer (score 9):

I always add "Immigration status:  permanent resident" to my cv in Germany.

I add it in the section with my basic personal stats so it's front and center in my application.

You could also mention it in your cover letter.

Comment: I've seen this on resumes in the US, and it's never raised eyebrows as far as I know.

Answer (score 5):

**Nationality: American**

or, for example

**Nationality: British. Permanent US Resident / Green Card holder**

Most HR staff will understand visas as it applies to their company, but no harm in making it obvious.

Comment: Unless the OP is already naturalized, his/her nationality is not American yet.

Comment: "Nationality: American" can be a material misrepresentation for a green card alien, not just a technicality. I had to give a class for some customer programmers at my then employers Virginia office. If I had been a US citizen I could have given it at the customer's office.

Comment: You would use "Nationality: American" only if you were a legal American citizen; I used it to compare and contrast the second option, where they would be a green card holder. I should have made that more obvious. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

> I am concerned if I apply, having a foreign name and nationality, they will assume that I am also not local and in need of an H1-B visa

You're running very fast based on this assumption here.  No one really cares what your name is -- with the exception (I'm sorry to say) of Muslim names.  Let your experience be the thing that attracts readers to contact you.  That's the whole point of the resume.  Since your green card gives you the right to work wherever you please, it doesn't make any sense to make it an issue.

Leave it off the resume in lieu of better things to put in the same space.

I'm a natural-born citizen; I don't speak with an accent, and during my last job search, every person I contacted asked about my work status.  It's not a big deal.  Don't make it one.

Comment: True about the name. My surname is of Irish descent, but I'm not now, never have been, and never will be, Irish.